# Highcharts/Stockcharts stack series separately

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking into trying to stack completely different series/charts on top of each other but on the same chart.  For instance I could have two charts stacked vertically and when I move the cross-hair on one, it will move on the other almost as if the charts are linked.  As well, I'd when I zoom in one, it would trigger the other to zoom.  Please see the image at the bottom I "doctored" to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Things I've tried:

1. creating two completely separate charts and stacking them.

   - This is the closest I've gotten to what I need but they are still separate entities so it won't work for what I need, cross-hairs/zooming/etc. all need to work as though the charts are linked/combined.
2. In the options I tried the "stacking" option.

   - this won't work because it "stacks" or groups data, I want to literally have two separate series that might not have anything in common with each other.
3. Rendering muliple y-axis.

   - the only issue with this is that it's overlapped data, I'd like it to be offset so we can see it in a stacked layout.

I'm pretty new to using this library so if any of my terminology or explanation doesn't sound right, please sound off and I'll elaborate.

Thanks everyone!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Take a look: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Comment: Thank you for that link Pawel, exactly what I was looking for!!